# How do you print the current time in the LLDB debugger?

Tags: xcode, lldb

How do you do it? I am using XCode 4.5.2 and trying to make timestamps for an operation that's executing in the background.

Comment: What do you mean, by the current time ?
Typing `po [NSdate date]` in the debugger will show you the current time, but I'm not sure if that's what you want

Answer (score 13, accepted):

While calling `po [NSDate date]` will give you the current time, it will involve running code in the target program, which is fairly slow, so you might not want to do that for instance in a breakpoint command that gets hit frequently.

If you want to do this without running code, the trick is to remember that lldb's "script" command gives you access to a full-on Python interpreter.  So for instance:

```
(lldb) script import time
(lldb) script time.ctime()
'Thu Nov  7 12:21:22 2013'
```